# XSLT Calling mydefined function from another xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In the code below, I want to define a function in one xsl file and include it in another xsl and then call it. I am trying to return a boolean. I just started with XSLT. Working code or sample will be appreciated.

The code below throws an error:

> ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function
>   'notMissingAndNull' is not a valid object reference.' FATAL ERROR: 
>   'The first argument to the non-static Java function
>   'notMissingAndNull' is not a valid object reference.'

First XSLT: CommonFunctions.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:func="func:func"
    >


     <xsl:function name="func:notMissingAndNull" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="missing" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="after" as="xs:string"/> 
        <xsl:if test="$missing.length>0 and $after.length>0">
            <xsl:value-of select="true" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another XSLT: Functions getting called

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:func="func:func"
    >
    <xsl:import href="CommonFunctions.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
                    <xsl:if
                        test="@name = 'AC_NAME'">
                        <AccountName xpath="Account/{{accountId}}/AccountName"
                            mapRules="">
                            <xsl:value-of select="func:notMissingAndNull('missing','after')" />
                        </AccountName>
                    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? And what is `$missing.length>0` supposed to to? You have declared `missing` as a string, in XPath/XSLT to find out the length of  a string you would use `string-length($missing)`. Also if you want an XSLT 2.0 function to return a boolean value then you need to use e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="string-length($var) > 0"/>`, doing `<xsl:value-of select="true"/>` would try to rerturn a text node with the string value of the selected element named true of the context node, only inside the function there is not context node at all.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Can you please guide me how to call a function in xslt doesn;t matter if I use xslt version 1 or 2. I tried some samples but didn't worked for me.I want to create one common xsl with only functions and to call another xsl by importing it.

Comment: The second example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35037483/252228 for instance has an example of XSLT 2.0 calling a function defined in an imported stylesheet module. XSLT 1.0 does not support that feature in general, there you would really first need to share which XSLT processor exactly you use to allow us to make suggestions on how to make use of extensions to define and/or call functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34974459/252228 is another example of XSLT 2.0 defining a function using `xsl:function` and calling it.